# Relocate a LAN cable without breaking the network

Tags: networking, lan, cable

For some years the cable was laying under a bedroom door. 
Now I need to slightly move it. To get a better idea:

[image]

On the left is the current "cable status" and on the right is how I want to make it.
My problem is the cable isn't that long and I need to use a second cable to achieve this. Here comes the main problem - I'm using the cable for two computers. It is a straight cable with four RJ-45.

So I wonder if I get 2 [RJ45 Lan Connectors](http://idh.jebolist.com/AC01-01-0009/001.jpg) and put them at [the green circles](http://i39.tinypic.com/15y9he1.jpg), then connect the two lan cables would that work properly? I only need to extend the cable.

Is there another approach to this problem?
Any suggestions are welcome! :)

Edit:
The cable is going all around the apartment. Probably it's about 20-25meters long until it goes into my server. The cable goes behind many heavy furniture and though a couple of walls. That's why I'm looking for an alternative way. :)

Comment: How long is the cable in total? And what is running over the cable? (Is it 10Mbps? 100Mbps? 1000Mbps?)

Comment: I'm guessing the cable is under carpet or something? Which would explain why you won't want to run new cable all the way? Yes, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It's going all around the apartment. Probably it's about 20-25meters long until it goes into my server. The cable goes behind many heavy furniture and a couple of walls... That's why I don't want to get a new cable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I get 2 RJ45 Lan Connectors and put them at the green circles, then connect the two lan cables would that work properly?

Yes, it will work properly (if you connect all properly)

I just note - in order to decrease "points of failures" *if* you *can pull* cable near the door, **I would** have thought about single connection (pull existing cable, place around the door, missing a few meters near server fill by new short cable /connector-socket-connector/, or cable plus )

Answer (score 5):

Get a longer ethernet cable, it probably won't be that expensive, and much more reliable.

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that too. It's definitely the "right" way to go, though it won't be as easy as it sounds. (Look at my edit).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on cutting the existing cable and crimping on two new RJ45s so you actually splice the new cable in the middle like you drew ( bad idea ), you only need one coupler to connect the end of the existing cable to the new one, somewhere between the door and wherever it ultimately goes.

Comment: but if he intends to do that, he might as well get fresh cable and crimp it

Answer (score 1):

Figure out your hourly rate and the cost of new cabling, then buy a switch or hub for that price.

Comment: I don't see why I would use a switch/hub for this task?